# How can I make two types recognized as different by the compiler but being the same one in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, types

For instance, suppose a C program is designed to drive an oven, where unsigned integer types are used for `temperature` and `heat` power.

It would be safe to get a compile error if a `temperature` variable is used to set the `heat` power by mistake.

With two `typedef`s to define two `uint` aliases for `temperature` and `heat`, the compiler would not complain if they are swapped by mistake.

With two different structures with one `uint` field, the compiler would complain if they are swapped by mistake, but the code would be longer because of the extra redundant syntax to access the single inner field. Moreover, I am afraid a single field structure may take more memory than its field.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: C and C++ don't make you pay for what you don't use, so the size of your structures will be the same as the size of the one integer they contain, and byt the time the compiler's through optimizing there should be no speed loss. All of the pain should be in the "more typing" side.

Comment: In C, what you describe is about as elegant as you can get. But in C++, you can give the structs constructors, conversion operators, and arithmetic operators, to  let them convert to/from unsigned integers, and hide the syntax needed to access the data field, thus making the structs feel and act more like native integers to outside code, without giving up the type safety you are looking for.

Comment: I have raised a separate question about the size of a single field structure in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704434/is-the-size-of-a-single-field-struct-always-the-same-size-as-the-field

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel has an interesting technique for this — essentially the solution you outline in your second paragraph.  That is, IMO, the solution you should use.

For your scenario, create two structure types, like this:

```
typedef struct Power { unsigned value; } Power;
typedef struct Temperature { unsigned value; } Temperature;
```

Now define your variables of the appropriate type (the braces around the initializer are required; they'd be optional if the the types were typedefs for integer type):

```
Power power = { 32 };
Temperature temp = { 100 };
```

Suppose you have a function that takes arguments of these two types, such as:

```
void display_power_and_temp(Power p, Temperature t);
```

Now you can't write:

```
display_power_and_temp(temp, power);
```

because of the type mismatches.

BUT: the structures can be passed by value just as efficiently as integer values can be passed, and they can be returned from functions.  If you actually need to access the value, you can do so:

```
void display_power_and_temp(Power p, Temperature t)
{
    printf("Power:       %5u\n", p.value);
    printf("Temperature: %5u\n", t.value);
}
```

If necessary, you can use `p.value` or `t.value` in arithmetic computations, etc:

```
void increment_temperature(Temperature *temp, Temperature inc)
{
    temp->value += inc.value;
}
```

(or the increment could be a signed integer, or …).

There is no space overhead using this solution.  There is no extra cost when passing values to or from functions.  There is the slight notational overhead of specifying `.value` or `->value` when you need the values, but in return you get the type safety you desire.  The computational cost is zero.

This is the technique I'd recommend you use to achieve the type safety that is desirable.

Comment: Just a out everything you described is exactly what the OP said they DON'T want.

Comment: Yes, @RemyLebeau, and I'm telling the OP that their fears are essentially groundless (there's no overhead except in the use of the member access notation — which has zero cost in terms of space and time).