# Is the size of a single-field struct always the same size as the field?

Tags: c, struct

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75703300/how-can-i-make-two-types-recognized-as-different-by-the-compiler-but-being-the-s), the OP is worried that the size of a single-field struct may be larger than the size of the field, but is that worry justified?

The C17 standard mentions that there can be no padding before the first field (6.7.2.1-15) and allows for an amount of padding after the last element (6.7.2.1-17) which is unspecified at least in that clause.

So it seems the standard allows for the struct to be larger than the field (unless I have overlooked a clause?), but I guess this is only relevant for multi-field structs (to have correct alignment in e.g. an array of structs having an `int` and `char` field).

Could there be a situation where the size of a single-field struct is larger than the size of the field, i.e. where it would make sense for a compiler to insert padding at the end of a such a struct?

Comment: Are you asking about the standard, or whether it would ever make sense?

Comment: @PaulHankin Both. It seems the standard opens for it, but I do not see how it could ever make sense.

Comment: nielsen, IIRC `struct` and `char` alignment requirements may differ, so No, size of a single-field struct is not always the same size as the field.  I suppose there is a concern about memory efficiency.  "all structure or union types all of whose elements have types with fundamental alignment requirements and none of whose elements have an alignment specifier specifying an alignment that is not a fundamental alignment." may apply.  C17 § 6.2.8 2

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am not sure, but I do not think `struct` alignment is a fixed thing. To me it does not make sense that a `struct` should have higher alignment requirements than the largest alignment requirement of its members, however, it is very possible that the standard keeps this more open.

Comment: @nielsen As Paul Hankin commented, "Are you asking about the standard, or whether it would ever make sense? "

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica As I replied Paul Hankin: Both. (1) Am I correct that the standard opens for a single-field struct to have larger size than its field  (2) If so, is there an example where this is the case or would make sense?

Comment: The standard allows a C implementation to insert “unnecessary” padding at the end of a structure, and one reason we might want to do this is for debugging—adding padding could help detect or diagnose errors in mishandling pointers or address calculations, such as overrunning a buffer.

Comment: My quick thought goes also to defining an array of such struct. I would find very reasonable for a compiler to pad each struct at the end, to make next element reside on the proper boundary

Comment: @LuC Right, but an array of the field type (no struct) would not add padding (arrays are not allowed to have padding between their elements), so on the other hand it is hard to see why padding would be needed in one case and not the other.

Comment: @nielsen I admit to being more a user, than a profitable student of standards. What I was referring to is one element of the array `struct Mine { char foo; } bar [10];` What I ask myself is why then permit padding at the end of structures? I find that some memory access features can help when elements are accessed in that array, on some architectures - like working on 8 bytes boundaries for x86. It's clear also that the optimization level can just simplify it **a lot**

Comment: @LuC It makes good sense to generally permit padding at end of structs. Suppose we have `struct A {uint32_t a; char b;};` . This will most likely result in a structure where `a` is stored in the first 4 bytes, then `b` in the fifth byte. If we had an array of such structs and no padding were allowed at the end of the structure, then the second struct in the array would be at an unaligned offset of 5 which could be a problem as you say. This can be resolved by added 3 padding bytes at the end to ensure 4-byte alignment. However, this issue cannot happen with a single-field structure.